# What is the default working directory of a Delphi or C++Builder application

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I'm maintaining a few old applications written in Delphi 6 and C++Builder 4. Applications compiled with either compiler exhibit a phenomenon that seems strange. They tend to remember their default working directory, even when the .exe is copied to a different directory. What's the mechanism for determining the default working directory and how to know when the default working directory is *not* the same directory the .exe is located in?

Example: Let's say I have the source code and a compiled 32 bit PE `MyApp.exe` in `C:\CppBuilder\Projects\MyApp`. Then I copy `MyApp.exe` and other files from that folder to a USB flash disk `F:\`. Then, in Explorer, I doubleclick `MyApp.exe` in `F:\` and the application starts. Files opened with fopen are still opened from `C:\CppBuilder\Projects\Myapp`. If I rename or delete the  folder `C:\CppBuilder\Projects\Myapp`, then the input files are opened from `F:\` as I would expect. Also the default folder for file open dialogs works similarly.

What is the underlying mechanism for this?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I really can't find the answer, I'm embarrassed to say, and it's been driving me crazy from time to time. I'd like to be *sure* about where files are opened from, without using full paths in file names. Again, I am sorry. Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: *They tend to remember their default working directory, even when the .exe is copied to a different directory.* That's a feature of modern OS's

Comment: The initial working directory of a process is the folder the EXE is run from, unless the EXE is launched by another app, in which case the initial working directory is the parent process's working directory unless it specifies otherwise (via a parameter of `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute/Ex()`, for instance). What you describe should not be happening for `fopen()` (you shouldn't be using relative paths with it, anyway).

Comment: File dialogs, on the other hand, are something completely different. They have their own rules for how they determine the initial directory they display. The calling process's working directory is only one of many factors they consider. The particular rules are documented in MSDN for the file dialog API functions.

Comment: If you use relative file names then you are getting what you ask for. You don't control the working directory. You say you don't want to use absolute paths but that's the problem. Do the right think. Use absolute paths. Problem solved.

Comment: I usually set the directories of any dialog boxes or file explorers at start of my apps relative to exe path obtained with `ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName);` to avoid such problems ...
`

Comment: Although your question seems clear on the surface, there are broader underlying issues. I suggest [edit] your question with a [mcve] to provide a better question/answer pair.

Comment: @Spektre Application installation path is rarely a good choice as the default for dialog boxes/file explorers. (There are exceptions), but usually you're leading the user to place where files would be modified. And it's better for such files to be in an appropriate "data" folder; not somewhere that should ideally be locked down and non-writable for outside of administrative/installation tasks.

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of Windows 7 and later, in the underlying call to [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetSaveFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928(v=vs.85).aspx).

Specifically, the documentation for the `lpstrInitialDir` field of the [`OPENFILENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) structure says:

> lpstrInitialDir
>   Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The initial directory. The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.
>
> Windows 7:
>
> 1. **If lpstrInitialDir has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an Open or Save As dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.**
> 2. Otherwise, if lpstrFile contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if lpstrInitialDir is not NULL, it specifies the initial directory.
> 4. If lpstrInitialDir is NULL and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.
>
> Windows 2000/XP/Vista:
>
> 1. If lpstrFile contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, lpstrInitialDir specifies the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory. However, if an application is not run for a long time, its saved selected path is discarded.
> 4. If lpstrInitialDir is NULL and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.

Furthermore, calls to the common file dialog, unless made with the `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag set, [will continuously change your application's working directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101112-00/?p=12293) to the last one selected in that dialog - this whether a file was selected/saved or not.  Even if `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` is specified the working directory still changes as the user navigates the dialog but is restored when the dialog closes.  This makes relative paths particularly unsafe in multithreaded contexts.

`fopen` will use the current working directory when opening files with relative paths so these calls would be affected ony if the application had previously either changed its working directory or had it changed by making calls to a common file dialog as above.

Comment: Also note that `GetOpenFileName()`/`GetSaveFileName()` alter the calling process's current working directory while the user navigates from folder to folder. If you DO NOT specify the `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag in the `OPENFILENAME::Flags` field, the original current working directory will not be restored when the dialog closes.

Comment: Questions says **Files opened with fopen**

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `fopen` uses the current working directory, afaik, and it is the calls to the dialog functions that are changing this.

Comment: Sure, if the file dialog is opened first

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of Delphi and C++ builder apps is the same as in the most other apps. And GetCurrentDir always returns correct working directory that is exe directory by default. But in VCL Open/Save dialogs if you don't specify **InitialDir** property when they use the last used directory.

Comment: No. By default it is the working directory of the parent process. But the shell sets it to the exe directory when you double click an exe.

Comment: Sure, By default here I mean from user point of view when you double click on file (as specified in the question)